# Multiple Bar graphs in single figure matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot two bar graphs in a single figure as you can see `nrows=1, ncols=2,` I have created 2 columns but unable to utilize it, however, the code works fine the only problem is, it prints two bar graphs separately and I want them to be printed in a single graph.
Looking forward to a *friend in need is a friend indeed* who can guide me. Thanks

[Required_File](https://file.io/u7wdK3qC7xii)

[Desired_Output](https://pasteboard.co/JVLAdSl.png)

[Current Program Output](https://ibb.co/Nt1fsmb)

```
import pandas as pandas
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width=0.2

fig,ax= plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']
labels = ('Cyber incident', 'Theft of paperwork or data storagedevice', 'Rogue employee', 'Social engineering / impersonation')
identify=['Health service providers','Finance','Education','Legal,accounting & management services','Personal services']

df = pd.read_csv('Malicious_or_criminal_attacks_breakdown-Top_five_industry_sectors_July-Dec-2019.csv', index_col=0, engine='python') # opening the file
df = pd.DataFrame(df)


data = df.values.tolist()

# Set position of bar on X axis
# -----------------------------------

br = [np.arange(len(data[0]))]
for i in range(len(data)):
    br.append([x + width for x in br[i-1]])
    br.append([x + width for x in br[i-1]])

for i in range(len(br)):
    if(i==4):
        break
    plt.bar(br[i], data[i], color =colors[i], width = width,
        edgecolor ='grey', label =labels[i])
    # Adding Xticks
    plt.ylabel('Number Of Attacks', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 15)
    plt.title('Type of attack by top five industry sectors')
    plt.xticks([r + width for r in range(len(data[i]))],
            identify[:],rotation=89.5)


plt.legend()  
plt.show()
# -----------------------------------------------
arr = np.array(data)
n_groups, N = arr.shape
ind=np.arange(N)
p=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    p.append(plt.bar(ind, data[i], width))
# for 
plt.ylabel('Number Of Attacks', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 15)
plt.title('Type of attack by top five industry sectors')
plt.xticks(ind+width/2, identify[:],rotation=89.5)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 80, 20))
for i in range (len(p)-1):
    plt.legend(labels[:])
 

plt.show()
```